# Running my pathfinding calculations in a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

I am very new to threads and I want to have my pathfinder run on it separate thread.

For a low amount of units (that all request a path when the game opens) it works for a while but then I get a `NullPointerException` and a `IllegalThreadStateException`.

```
...
GoTo: New path for nr: 10. [9ms]
Item: item  picked up by: nr: 2
Item: item picked up by: nr: 0
GoTo: New path for nr: 1. [10ms]
GoTo: New path for nr: 2. [2ms]
GoTo: New path for nr: 0. [3ms]
Item: item dropped by: nr: 11
Item: item dropped by: nr: 2
Item: item dropped by: nr: 12
Item: item  dropped by: nr: 20
Item: item  dropped by: nr: 0
Exception in thread "Thread-38" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.down(BinaryHeap.java:124)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.remove(BinaryHeap.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.pop(BinaryHeap.java:60)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.search(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:113)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:93)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:50)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.getPath(GoTo.java:93)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.access$000(GoTo.java:18)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo$1.run(GoTo.java:47)
GoTo: New path for nr: 2. [27ms]
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:684)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.perform(GoTo.java:62)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.Hauling.perform(Hauling.java:40)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Creature.update(Creature.java:52)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.CreatureHandler.update(CreatureHandler.java:50)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.World.TestMap.update(TestMap.java:114)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.BuriedKingdoms.render(BuriedKingdoms.java:49)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
GoTo: New path for nr: 12. [1ms]
GoTo: New path for nr: 20. [4ms]
GoTo: New path for nr: 0. [27ms]
```

I first tried starting the thread in the constructor of where I need the path. I used to look it up there before I started threading. Now I moved it to the method that is called in a update loop but I get the same results.

```
public GoTo(final Creature creature, final Coordinate coordinate) {
        test = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                getPath(creature, coordinate);
            }
        };
        //getPath(creature, coordinate); //Old way without threads
    }
```

Following gets called every frame but it should not call the thread multiple times since it checks if it's alive and when it's finished it should have a path.

```
@Override
public boolean perform(final Creature creature) {
    if (path == null)
    {
        if (!test.isAlive())
            test.start();


        return false;
    }
```

I started with this thread code in the constructor:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getPath(creature, coordinate);
        }
    }).start();
```

If I put 100 units in my game on a 1000x1000 man things start going wrong right away.

```
"C:\Program ...
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.down(BinaryHeap.java:115)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.remove(BinaryHeap.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.pop(BinaryHeap.java:60)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.search(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:113)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:93)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:50)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.getPath(GoTo.java:82)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.access$000(GoTo.java:18)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo$1.run(GoTo.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.search(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:114)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:93)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:50)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.getPath(GoTo.java:82)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.access$000(GoTo.java:18)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo$1.run(GoTo.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
GoTo: New path for nr: 2. [2ms]
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.down(BinaryHeap.java:124)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.remove(BinaryHeap.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.pop(BinaryHeap.java:60)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.search(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:113)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:93)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:50)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.getPath(GoTo.java:82)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.access$000(GoTo.java:18)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo$1.run(GoTo.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Exception in thread "Thread-8" Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.down(BinaryHeap.java:134)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.remove(BinaryHeap.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.pop(BinaryHeap.java:60)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.search(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:113)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:93)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:50)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.getPath(GoTo.java:82)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.access$000(GoTo.java:18)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo$1.run(GoTo.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.down(BinaryHeap.java:134)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.remove(BinaryHeap.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BinaryHeap.pop(BinaryHeap.java:60)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.search(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:113)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:93)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.ai.pfa.indexed.IndexedAStarPathFinder.searchNodePath(IndexedAStarPathFinder.java:50)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.getPath(GoTo.java:82)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.access$000(GoTo.java:18)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo$1.run(GoTo.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
GoTo: New path for nr: 7. [2ms]
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.NullPointerException
GoTo: New path for nr: 9. [0ms]
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

To add to this, I do not care if the path finding takes a couple of seconds I just don't want my framerate to drop because some paths take >100ms on the larger map.

-Edit-

I have tried with it with future task:

public GoTo(final Creature creature, final Coordinate coordinate) {

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    task = new FutureTask(new GetPath(creature.getLocation(), coordinate));
    executor.execute(task);

            try {
                path = (List<Coordinate>)task.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    //getPath(creature, coordinate);
}
```

`GetPath` implements `Callable` and seems to work in the above example. But there it just waits for the task/thread to finish so I have the same results as without threads, framedrop.

I would have expected this to work in my gameloop:

```
            if (task.isDone())
            {
                try {
                    path = (List<Coordinate>)task.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else return false;
```

But it yields `NullPointerExceptions`.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.GoTo.perform(GoTo.java:56)
    at com.buckriderstudio.buriedkingdoms.Creatures.Jobs.Hauling.perform(Hauling.java:40)
//....
```

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? I wanted to post a comment but since you deleted it that was not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use a thread to compute some result and do not want to manage the life-cycle of it, try using the `FutureTask` and `ExecutorService` in concurrency package.

I found a sample [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/futuretask/java-util-concurrent-futuretask-example/).

And I strongly recommend you to read the 《Java Concurrency in Practice》, if you want to really understand these issues.

Comment: The sample is nice but the functionality is exactly the same as without Threads. In the for loop it just waits for the threads to finish thus I get frame drops. Somehow I cannot do `if (task.isDone)` and put the `try/catch` in there in my gameloop since I get other `NullPointerExceptions`.